# FFmpeg: what's the difference betwen av_opt_set and av_dict_set?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming

What is the difference av_opt_setxx and av_dict_set,
according to what I have found, if you want to set things like

> rtbuffersize

or

> rtsp_transport

, you use the av_dict_set.

Can I set all options through av_dict_set? If so, what's the purpose of av_opt_set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`av_opt_set` will set the option name+value pair directly on an object. `av_dict_set` will cache the option name+value pair in a dictionary structure, which can then be applied to an object, or (re)used for debugging, inspection, etc.

So a dict (in this particular case) is nothing more than an intermediate cache for option name/value pairs before you apply them on an object.